# Problem with significance test using stat_signif() coupled with a ggplot2 boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to produce a boxplot with the results of a significance text, ideally with Student's test and/or a Wilcoxon's test comparing two groups of concentrations between two
different auto-analysers. If I run the following code (Note the code does not include the input statements for the datafiles but it does have all of the libraries used in the program although many are not applicable to the histogram part of the code):

```
library(tidyverse) #Data frame creation manipulation
library(tidyquant) #Specialized quantifications - may or may not use
library(timetk)    #Updating dates amd other time series data 
library(purrr)     #Programming toolkit for R
library(reshape2)  #Data manipulation tools

library(openxlsx) #Access to Excel xlsx files 
library(labelled) #labelling  var_label list functions used for creating variable labels and 
                  #labels for plots using output

library(ggplot2)  
library(ggsignif) #Significance tests in ggplot
library(rstatix)  #Shapiro-Wilks Test
library(tseries)  #Jarque-Bera test
library(Hmisc)    #describe function
library(ggcorrplot)
library(ggpubr)
library(gt)
library(scales)
library(table1)
library(moments)


df2 <-  df[c("station","date","method1","method2")]
df2 <-  melt(df2, id.var=c("station","date"))
df2 <- rename(df, Autoanalyser=variable, Concentration=value)
str(df2)
df2

ggplot(df2, aes(x=Autoanalyser, y=Concentration)) + geom_boxplot() + 
                geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("method1", "method2"),
```

test = "t.test"),
map_signif_level=TRUE)

R does produce a nice boxplot as shown here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTV7V.png)

however it does not provide the significance results. From what I can tell the code should be correct. Nevertheless R provides me with the typically and wonderfully cryptic message which informs me of nothing and follows below:

**Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_signif()`
Caused by error in `if (scales$x$map(comp[1]) == data$group[1] | manual) ...`:
! missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed**

Oddly enough I can get significance test results to be displayed IF I remove the test="t.test" option. But then how am I to know which test is being used? There are several possibilities available. Anyone out there have a clue?

Here are the data:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJZT0.png)

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my own question which involved employing the t_test function of the rstatix package coupled with the stat_pvalue_manual option in ggplot. I believe I've generalized the code well enough for the most inexperienced of users to understand it.

```
stat.test <- df %>% t_test(y ~ group, paired = TRUE) #<---Paired T-test
stat.test
   
# Box plot
ggplot(sifdat2, aes(x=group, y=y)) + geom_boxplot() + 
                   stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test, label = "p", y.position = 1.25)
```